# Symfony: problems with disabling debug in prod environment

Tags: symfony

I have uploaded a site created with Symfony 3 on a shared server and everything is going perfectly well, but for some reason, when I want to disable debug mode for production, I get a fatal `Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Loader'` error, no matter what I try to load.

If I set the debug mode to `true` again, I have no more problems. Anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: Did you tried to launch "cache:clear --env=prod" from CLI ? Then check that the directory "var/cache/" is writable.

Comment: Making the cache file writable doesn't help. As for clearing cache, I've installed the coresphere console bundle just for that purpose, but every time I try to clear the cache, I get an internal server error (it happens in local as well; not with command line but with the console bundle, it seems I can't clear the cache).

Comment: What steps did you use to deploy the app? Have you set proper access permissions on the directory of the project?